# Atom : Quick Documentation of React Native

Tags: android, atom-editor, react-native, nuclide-editor

I have worked on android platform now switching to different platform `react-native`. I am using `atom` text editor to code for `react-native` apps.

I have installed two packages in atom A) Linter B) Nuclide

Now, I want to have quick documentation of methods of `react-native` on pressing shortcut or hover on method name. Isn't there any package to have quick documentation as like other tools Android Studio/Eclipse has.

As of now I have to go their documentation website to look and come back.

```
AppRegistry.registerComponent('XYZ', () => XYZ);
```

Something like https://i.stack.imgur.com/EoB87.png http://i0.wp.com/www.innovatecode.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/Android-Studio-Quick-Documentation.png?fit=455%2C280

[image]

Comment: Join us on the [vscode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense) side have cookies and great intellisense. In the likes of visual studio and the intellij platform :). Also its about 4-5x faster ;)

Comment: I am using vscode but for nodejs stuff not for react native

Comment: Well vscode as great if not better support for react-native with this extension : https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-react-native

Answer (score 0):

Atom does not have inbuilt support for viewing documentation of a selected object. However, you can use **[atom-ternjs](https://atom.io/packages/atom-ternjs)** package which adds JavaScript code intelligence for atom. Once atom-ternjs is installed, to view the documentation of an object (method, class etc.) just place your cursor over the object and press `alt+o` (windows, mac, linux).

atom-ternjs provides many other tools for javascript which can be found in it's documentation - https://atom.io/packages/atom-ternjs.

**Old Answer** - for viewing shortcuts or list of commands in atom.

Atom has an inbuilt command palette which can be used to get a list of actions that can be performed by the editor along with it's shortcut keys. You can open the command palette by pressing `ctrl+shift+p` on windows/linux and by pressing `cmd+shift+p` on Mac. Once you open the command palette you can search for the required action easily.

Comment: No, I want something like this on pressing shortcut key on method https://i.stack.imgur.com/1LLBK.png https://i.stack.imgur.com/EoB87.png

Comment: sorry I misunderstood the documentation part. Give me some time, i'll find a solution.

Comment: No problem! Sure Dani! Thanks :)

Comment: I believe atom-ternjs will provide documentation for JS only, I am looking for React Native

Comment: Yup, but it has completely different methods, class, properties

Comment: Sure,  I am out, will try tomorrow.